# can not get extras from intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I tried to get a latitude and longitude back from google maps activity and I always get the default value if I try to use getDoubleExtra of null if I'm using getStringExtra
here is my code from the Google maps activity:

```
public void onOkClick(View v){                                        
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "we will save the place",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent back= this.getIntent();
    back.putExtra("latitude",latitudeB);
    back.putExtra("longitude",longitudeB);
    setResult(RESULT_OK,back);
    finish();

}
```

this is the reciving part:

```
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestcode, int resultcode,Intent data){                   
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode,resultcode,data);
    if(resultcode==RESULT_OK&&requestcode==PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
        Bundle B=data.getExtras();
        String la=B.getString("latitude");
        String lo=data.getStringExtra("longitude");
        placee.setText(""+la+"   "+lo);
}
}
```

Comment: Why not say `Intent intent = new Intent();`

Comment: what is the type latitudeB in onOkCLick

Comment: it's a global variable, it works now.. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are trying to transition back to the calling activity, you can create a new Intent and set the values accordingly:

```
public void onOkClick(View v){                                        
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "we will save the place",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   Intent back= new Intent();
   back.putExtra("latitude",latitudeB);
   back.putExtra("longitude",longitudeB);
   setResult(RESULT_OK,back);
   finish();
 }
```

Try this and let me know how it goes; because `getIntent()` could return null!

All the best!